# Emacs maximized but leaves few pixels in Awesome WM

Tags: emacs, awesome-wm

I love emacs and Awesome WM.

But dont know why, but when I maximize the emacs, it always leaves few pixels in Awesome WM. I've tried font_size_honor=false for emacs class in rc.lua but it just does not work.

[image]

You can see from image that emacs always leaves some pixels at bottom. My dekstop background i black in color, so it is not very clearly visible.

I would appreciate any comments, suggestions or may be a fix for this problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've this in my rc.lua:

```
   { rule = { class = "Emacs" },
     properties = { size_hints_honor = false } },
```

And Emacs does fullscreen. That said, it won't change much: I don't see my background anymore, but Emacs do nothing of the added space.

Comment: AFAICS, Emacs now fills that extra space.